# Send a Copy of email to Sender PHP contact script

Tags: php, email

i am using the below PHP Script to get emails to my from my contact form. i want to send a copy of the same email to the sender email also. how can i do that... can some one add some lines to my script to do that..

can i separate multiple emails in $emailTo like `$emailTo = 'owner@website.com, $email';`

```
if(!isset($hasError)) {

    $emailFrom = 'smptcontactemail@website.com';
    $emailTo = 'owner@website.com';
    $subject = 'Submitted message from '.$name;
    $sendCopy = trim($_POST['sendCopy']);
    $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nComments: $comments";
    $headers = 'From: ' .' <'.$emailFrom.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

    mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);

    // set our boolean completion value to TRUE
    $emailSent = true;
}
```

Adding another FUNCTION might work. but i am searching for some other easy way to do that in same function :)

PS: i want to add a aditional line to sender like "your email copy of message that you sent to xxx owner"

Comment: The built-in PHP `mail()` function is seriously lacking in functionality, plus security often is a problem as soon as you start writing your own mail headers (your code could likely be hacked easily to send spam). I therefore **strongly** recommend using a decent mailer class like PHPMailer or Swiftmailer when writing PHP programs to send emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [php.net/mail](http://php.net/mail) example #4 on how to extend the `$additional_headers` parameter to add a CC recipient:

`$headers = 'From: ' .' <'.$emailFrom.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n" . 'Cc: ' .' <some@mail.com>';`

Answer (score 4):

That will be

```
$headers .= 'Cc: anotheremail@domain.net' . "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps

```
<?php
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $email_address = $_POST['email'];
            $phone = $_POST['phone'];
            $course = $_POST['course'];

// Create the email and send the message

            $to = $email_address; //This is the email address of the person who filled the form, this email will be supplied by the sender.

            $email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";

            $email_body = "You have received a new message from your Website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\n
            Name: $name\n\n
            Email: $email_address\n\n
            Phone: $phone\n\n
            Course:\n$course";

            $headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.

            $headers .= 'Cc: youremail@yourdomain.com' . "\r\n"; // Add your email address  replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send the message to.

            $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 

            mail($to, $email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

            return true;            
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by writing

```
$emailTo = 'owner@website.com, customer@website.com';
```

Comment: and i want to send some additional line to the sender. like your email copy or something.....

Comment: In this case you need to send two separate mails and thus call mail() two times

Answer (score -2):

You can try like this to send a cc copy to sender email

```
$headers["From"] = "$from";
$headers["To"] = "$email";
$headers["Subject"] = $subject;
$headers['Cc'] = '$from';
```

Comment: mail() expects a string, not an array, for the additional parameters

Comment: The concept is right but the code isn't you need to append it see Alma Do Mundo's answer